# kdb: What is the meaning of this command line prompt q.Q)

Tags: kdb

The normal prompt is `q)`, what is the meaning of `q.Q)`?

I think I got stuck in this after pressing Ctrl-C while a query is running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means you've interrupted execution inside one of the .Q functions, see https://code.kx.com/q/ref/#q

You can usually return to the normal prompt by changing namespace back to the default namespace

```
\d .
```